# Does "color" in TERM always mean I can use colors?

Tags: bash, terminal, colors, bashrc, terminal-emulator

Should the following always indicate that I can use escape sequences and `tput` to colorize things?

```
if [[ $TERM == *"color"* ]]; then
  true
else
  false
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: the name of the terminal description is irrelevant.  `TERM` is the name of a terminal description.  There are a lot, and most of the terminals which support color do not have "color" in their names.  There is for instance no reason why a terminal description could not be named "no-color".

Programs that use the terminal description look at the *capabilities* listed in it.  There are of course a lot of hard-coded programs which assume things about the name of a terminal description.

According to the ncurses FAQ *[My terminal doesn't recognize color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#no_color)*, the terminal description should say how many colors the terminal supports, as well as how to set the foreground and background colors.

You can use [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) to obtain the number of colors:

```
colors=$(tput colors)
if [ $colors -gt 1 ]
```

since a missing `colors` capability makes `tput` return `-1`.

Comment: The `tput colors` in my terminal say `8` but the terminal does support 256 colors.

Comment: Then the choice of `TERM` is incorrect (for your purposes).  You could simply hardcode an assumption...

Comment: There is nothing incorrect in using an stock terminal app. Maybe it is you who should review your assumptions ...

Comment: To land in the middle. As question is *"always indicate"* I guess one could say that it is a in the middle per user configuration. If a user have chosen to use a no-color terminfo / termcap then that should likely be honored, even though the terminal might support colours. As well as if one use xterm even though it is *xterm-256colors* capable one are to use 8 and not 256 ...